# Intended Audience Header/Banner and Security Control

Tags: security

We are currently in SharePoint 2013 on-prem and soon to be in 2016 on-prem (we are not going to SharePoint online yet).

Our goal is to provide a clear statement/header/banner of who should have access to a SharePoint site throughout the site whether a user directly hits a list, library, calendar, etc.  We would like to utilize this header/banner to ensure correct permissions are being applied via defined security groups in a look up location (or some similar method), as well as report on any Team Members that fall outside correct permissions.

An example would be we've stated throughout the site that this SharePoint site is for management only, but a user with "Full Control" has added an intern by accident.  We need to be notified this intern was added or run a report showing this intern...and possibly more employees...fall outside the management team and need to be removed.

For now, we have a 'notice' on the home page via a Content Editor web part or hand entry on the top of a wiki page, but problems with this approach are:

1. Banner is just text…no underlying process to enforce permissions +
   provide reporting.
2. It is only visible on the home page + can be placed anywhere on the home page (i.e. in web part, in top of wiki
   page area, etc.).
3. No standardization >> i.e. different acronyms or abbreviations for same words, groups, areas

An example of what we're looking for would be:

- Utilize the header/banner and use as lookup key Compare header to a
  ‘proper security’ lookup list to ensure correct permissions
- Report on any Team Members that fall outside correct permissions

Because we are moving to SharePoint 2016 on prem, we have investigated utilizing Site Closure and Deletion / Site Policy, but this just puts a stamp/image on the site @ the top of every location...which is great for a visual, but there is no supportive process to control permissions...it's just a visual indicator.

Please advise where we may start looking for a solution to:

1. Provide visual header/banner/statement throughout the site to state the intended audience
2. Utilize the header to see what permissions are applied
3. Report on the team members that fall outside the header/banner intended audience